# Face detection using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

tried this code

```
A=imread('1.jpg');


FaceDetector=vision.CascadeObjectDetector();


BBOX=step(FaceDetector,A);


B=insertObjectAnnotation(A,'rectangle',BBOX,'Face');


imshow(B),title('Detected Faces');


n=size(BBOX,1);

str_n=num2str(n);

str=strcat('number of detected faces are ',str_n);

disp(str);
```

this error show with me

Undefined function 'insertObjectAnnotation' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.

Error in Detected_faces (line 9)
B=insertObjectAnnotation(A,'rectangle',BBOX,'Face');

Comment: Incorrect javascript tag?

Comment: please add your image - I think it's just a matter of the type of your input.

Comment: Which version of MATLAB do you have? `insertObjectAnnotation` was introduced in version R2012b: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertobjectannotation.html

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the type of your image.
A type must be uint8 and the "insertObjectAnnotation" function only takes different inputs.

Please try:

```
A=imread('1.jpg');


FaceDetector=vision.CascadeObjectDetector();


BBOX=step(FaceDetector,A);


B=insertObjectAnnotation(rgb2gray(A),'rectangle',BBOX,'Face');
```

Actually, I tried this:

```
I = imread('coins.png');

FaceDetector=vision.CascadeObjectDetector();


BBOX=step(FaceDetector,I);


B=insertObjectAnnotation(I,'rectangle',BBOX,'Face');
```

And I is uint8, and it worked.

Using your dataset, it worked just fine. See Image output.[image]

Comment: @Osama upload your image please

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cu2u1d8b1n7hbn7/Dataset.rar?dl=0
i use images from this data set

Comment: Are you reading the image properly? Do you have the toolbox as well? Maybe it's one of this.. the rest is fine